# how to disable the dijit date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

i am using the date picker in an input field
the input field is disabled, but when I click on it, the date picker opens

any idea?

im disableing it with this

```
document.getElementById('id').readOnly = true;
```

Comment: This is not called disable it is called readonly.Use disable instead of readonly

Comment: tried it, but the picker still works

Comment: Show your updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example should work for you:

```
<div id="txtDate" jsId="txtDate" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox"></div>
```

---

```
require(['dojo/parser', 'dijit/form/DateTextBox']);

dojo.ready(function() {

    dijit.byId('txtDate').set('readonly', 'readonly');
    dijit.byId('txtDate').set('disabled', 'disabled');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as follow:-

```
$("#id").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also :

```
$("#id").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

OR :

```
$("#id").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```